# Spring boot with maven don`t copy resources dir

Tags: maven, spring-boot

I tryng to configure my spring-boot project with maven from https://start.spring.io/  (and select to generate a war file)

this is my pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>br.com.natal</groupId>
    <artifactId>integra</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>integra</name>
    <description>Integração para 7 Natal</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.7</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>19.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
            <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!--<dependency>-->
            <!--<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>-->
            <!--<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>-->
        <!--</dependency>-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

but when I run to build my project into a war file, the dir resources are not copied to .war.

I need to clean my project, run  mvn spring-boot:run, then build a war file.. so if I change one "," in my application.properties I need to do all again..

How can I fix this?

tks

Comment: how do you "build" your project ? only "mvn spring-boot:run" ?

Comment: what is your "dir" resources ?  What is your project's folder structure ?

Comment: my resources directory /src/main/resources

Comment: @Alex no i run mvn war (but to include the /src/main/resources) I need first to run mvn spring-boot:run

Answer (score 0):

You said you are building  as follow:

> i run mvn war (but to include the /src/main/resources) I need first to
>   run mvn spring-boot:run

- I assume you meant `mvn war:war`, however this does not trigger the spring-boot-maven-plugin.
- You should instead build the WAR with `mvn clean install`, then `spring-boot-maven-plugin` will be triggered and `repackage` into a valid spring-boot war.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue and my issue was due to a **silly** mistake. My resources folder name was wrong so spring-boot-maven plugin was not able to copied the resources.
My folder name was **resource**. After changing it to the required maven folder structure everything start working. 
Below is the plugin which i m using.

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
```

and below command i m using to generate the jar.

```
mvn -DskipTests clean compile package
```